# branches of git repo not showing in vscode using local devcontainer

Tags: git-branch, vscode-devcontainer, github-codespaces, remote-containers

I have a repo on github configured with codespaces. When opening codespaces on github in the cloud everything works and I can easily switch between branches.
Now I checked out the same repo locally on my windows machine an opened it with my local installed VScode. Again everything normal, and I can easily switch between different branches.
VScode now offers me to reopen in a devcontainer. I choose to do so and VScode starts building my local devcontainer, installing... After a while my devcontainer is ready and I can modify code and build (branch available is the one last used on the windows side). So far so good. However now I can not change branches in VScode anymore. Also when I click on the Git icon on the left of VScode I get a message saying:

*The folder currenlty open doesn't have a git repository.*

However in the terminal of the devcontainer I see my complete git repo (with all the git files) that is mounted from Windows. Changes done in the container are immediately reflected on Windows and vice versa as well (just checked this to make sure that it is properly mounted).

Any help is very welcomed.

Regards
Marc

Comment: Tried the same scenario on a Mac M1 and everything is working correctly i.e. I can normally switch between branches. Looks like this is a Windows related issue....

Comment: Better use WSL filesystem instead of Windows filesystem. There seems to be some compatible issue.